# What is the difference between perfectly nested loop and imperfectly nested loop?

Tags: algorithm, parallel-processing, parallels

I wanted to know what is the difference between perfectly nested loop and imperfectly nested loop?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See this: [openmp g++ error: collapsed loops not perfectly nested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13901673/openmp-g-error-collapsed-loops-not-perfectly-nested).

A perfectly nested loop is one wherein all content is in the *innermost* loop. For instance,

```
foreach(var a in vals1)
{
    foreach (var b in vals2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(a + b);
    }
}
```

As compared to an imperfectly nested one,

```
foreach(var a in vals1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("values for " + a);

    foreach (var b in vals2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(a + b);
    }
}
```

Of course, I'm a C# guy and this is C# where nobody I know of uses such terms and it doesn't matter at all, but you see the point.
 Just consider this pseudo-code that compiles under the right circumstances.