# If a loop nest has bound coming from the function argument in which it is present, can it be called a perfect loop nest?

Tags: c++, c, function, loops, nested-loops

Example :

```
void top(int *a, int *b)
 {
     L1 : for (int i = 0; i < *a; i++)
     {
         for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
         {
             *b += *a;
         }
     }
  }
```

Can I call the above nested loop L1 as perfect loop nest? A perfect loop nest should have constant bounds. I'm unclear if this situation comes into constant loop bound scenario.

Comment: From [what-is-the-difference-between-perfectly-nested-loop-and-imperfectly-nested-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24749801/what-is-the-difference-between-perfectly-nested-loop-and-imperfectly-nested-loop), *"A perfectly nested loop is one wherein all content is in the innermost loop"*. It is the case here.

Comment: Well, the label isn't in the inner loop... and should be removed since goto is considered harmful.

Comment: @Lundin: more to the point, the label is unused, so it should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Since the only statement in the body of the outer loop is the inner `for` loop, this nested `for` loop is a *perfectly nested loop*.

Note that neither **gcc** nor **clang** optimize the posted code beyond [simple unrolling](https://godbolt.org/z/cq9vE89P8) of the inner loop.

I wonder what compiler can reduce the code down to:

```
void top(int *a, int *b) {
    if (*a > 0)
        *b += *a * *a * 5;
}
```

Comment: Your "optimized" code is not correct if a and b point to the same int.

Comment: @gerum: that's true and it might explain the *limited* optimisation. Yet if `a` and `b` point to the same strictly positive `int`, running the function will keep increasing that until arithmetic overflow causes undefined behavior, so my version is just as good in this case :)