# OpenMP collapsed for with non-const values

Tags: c++, performance, parallel-processing, openmp

**Disclamer:** as you will see (in my opinion) this question is not related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13901673/openmp-g-error-collapsed-loops-not-perfectly-nested) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24749801/what-is-the-difference-between-perfectly-nested-loop-and-imperfectly-nested-loop).

I have this code:

```
std::vector<Wrapper> localWrappers;
std::vector<float> pixelDistancesNew;
std::vector<float> curSigmas;
//fill the 3 vectors
#pragma omp parallel for collapse(2) schedule(dynamic, 1)
for(int i=0; i<localWrappers.size(); i++)
  for (int r = par.border; r < (localWrappers[i].cur.rows - par.border); r++)
    for (int c = par.border; c < (localWrappers[i].cur.cols - par.border); c++) {
      const float val = localWrappers[i].cur.at<float>(r,c);
      if ( (val > positiveThreshold && (isMax(val, localWrappers[i].cur, r, c) && isMax(val, localWrappers[i].low, r, c) && isMax(val, localWrappers[i].high, r, c))) ||
        (val < negativeThreshold && (isMin(val, localWrappers[i].cur, r, c) && isMin(val, localWrappers[i].low, r, c) && isMin(val, localWrappers[i].high, r, c))) )
        // either positive -> local max. or negative -> local min.
        localizeKeypoint(r, c, curSigmas[i], pixelDistancesNew[i], localWrappers[i]);
    }
```

And I get this error:

```
error: parallel loops with collapse must be perfectly nested
    for(int i=0; i<localWrappers.size(); i++)
            ^

Error: the OpenMP "single" pragma must not be enclosed by the "for" pragma
```

Reading [this](http://dev-archive.ambermd.org/201509/0004.html), I think that the error is given by the fact that we I'm using `size()`. However, I don't know how could I get `const` for this or implementing any kind of solution for this problem.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Pretty sure the problem is in `localWrappers[i].cur.rows` and it's dependency on the outer loop variable. If that is constant for all `i`, then use an expression that doesn't depend on `i`. If it is not, you probably need to collapse the loops manually.

Comment: @Zulan well the problem is that that's not constant for all i

Comment: @Zulan What do you suggest to solve the problem?

Comment: @Zulan could you please give a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43844396/how-should-i-interpreter-these-vtune-results) question?